# MySQL: Set a 2 variables from 2 columns from a single table

Tags: mysql

In the LOAD DATA [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), there's a `SET` syntax which allows values to be assigned to column.

```
...
SET col=@variable;
...
```

I was wondering if the SET can support assignment from 2 columns from a single table, I can't find anything in the documentation that supports tuple assignment:

```
...
SET (col1, col2) = (SELECT col1, col2 from table where id=1);
...
```

Anyone have any knowledge on this? Thank you!

Comment: in short there can only be one value.. it's [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) in the manual

Comment: If you want to store that kind off data take a look into [temporary tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) you can just create a temporary just like a normal table with columns and indexes.. But only the current connection can see that temporary table just like the user variables you set with `SET @col = 'value';`

Comment: I see. Thanks Raymond!

Answer (score 0):

Set doesn't work like this, however I know that in TSQL at least you can do the same thing using select.

```
Select @var1 = col1, @var2= col2
from table
```